# What is the relationship between Motion Losses with gear ratio and speed in a moving vehicle

Tags: math, game-physics

I am a developer and I'm making a video game with a motorcycle.
I am pretty much finished and the only thing I have left is to find a formula for what concerns Losses in relationship with Gears and Speed.

Lets say that I have

Motion = Torque * GearRatio - Losses

I'm pretty sure that Losses should be something multiplied by GearRatio like so:

Losses = MotorcycleFriction * GearRatio

Now, it can't be just this. There has to be Motion involved in this formula. You cannot start a car in 5th gear but if you are already at 70km/h and shift to 5th, it's fine.

So Losses wold have to have a relationship with Motion as well

Kind of like this:

Losses = MotorcycleFriction * GearRatio / 0.5^Motion

...in fact it wouldn't matter that much if the formula was physically right, what I need is that Losses would be big at low speed and insignificant at high speed. That way the player would not be able to ride in 6th gear from the beginning to the end.

Anyone would like to comment or help by coming up with a nice non-linear curve that has a high Y when X is 0 and a Y tending to 1 on High X?

If you're a math guy,      y = a b^x    should say it all

If your a physics guy, have you got a formula involving all the terms above?

I know I'm almost there but this is the moment where I would make a google search and it's all polluted with those "Calculate your car gears" websites. I can't find much and I can't think this way anymore.

To be clear. I'm aware that there's other frictions involved, this is the simplified version...

Here's some data to give an idea of my setup:

```
0 <= Torque <= 1.                       

{ratio: 0, motMin: 0, motMax: 0, idealMin: -1},                 // N,
{ratio: 0.0000035, motMin: 0, motMax: 40, idealMin: 0},         // 1
{ratio: 0.0000065, motMin: 0, motMax: 75, idealMin: 20},         // 2
{ratio: 0.0000104, motMin: 35, motMax: 120, idealMin: 55},      // 3
{ratio: 0.00001475, motMin: 55, motMax: 170, idealMin: 100},    // 4
{ratio: 0.0000191, motMin: 100, motMax: 220, idealMin: 150}, // 5
{ratio: 0.000026, motMin: 150, motMax: 300, idealMin: 200},   // 6

MotorcycleFriction = 0.0000008
```

Torque, ratios and MotorcycleFriction are in coordinates while the minimums and maximums are in km/h (To explain the miss-match in the data)

To explain the data, if you enter a gear with a speed inferior to to idealMin (best speed to get into that gear) it applies a speed punishment. This works fine but I need something elegant where I can remove all the data above and only keep the ratios. This is not a real video game, it's a demo to find jobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain a few physics principles.

Your engine generates a certain amount of torque. Torque is a measure of the force that can act perpendicular to the axis of rotation in a certain distance. This torque is usually dependent on the frequency of your engine.

Through gears and tires, this torque is sooner or later converted into a linear force (usually in the forward direction of the vehicle). The force is therefore proportional to the torque and conversion ratios of the gear and tires (the higher your gear, the less force you get on the tires).

A linear force changes the velocity of the vehicle. The acceleration `a` that is generated can be calculated from the force `F` and the vehicle's mass `m` by:

```
a = F / m
```

This acceleration in turn affects the velocity of the vehicle. In video games, a common simplification is:

```
new velocity = old velocity + a * frame time
```

So far, we don't have any friction. You can model friction at the stage where you have a linear force acting on the vehicle. Friction is another force that acts in the opposite direction of movement and can be calculated as:

```
F_friction = F_N * mu
```

`F_N` is the normal force, which is perpendicular to the surface that you drive on. On a flat plane, this is simply the weight force of the vehicle (the heavier it is, the more friction you experience). `mu` is the friction coefficient. Actually, there are multiple friction coefficients, from which two are of interest to you:

The coefficient of static friction is the one that acts as long as the vehicle is standing still. The coefficient of kinetic or rolling friction is the one that acts after the vehicle has begun to move. The static friction coefficient is usually higher than the kinetic one.

So, now we have two forces: The one from the engine and the friction. Add them together and get the total force. Of course, friction will never cause a vehicle to accelerate. So, if e.g. your car is standing still and the friction force is higher than the engine force, you get a total force of zero and not a negative force. From this force, you can then continue to calculate acceleration and update vehicle velocities accordingly.

So why can't we start in fifth gear? In fifth gear, we have relatively little linear force. On the other hand, the static friction force is rather high and neutralizes the force we get from the engine. Therefore, we have to start at a lower gear, where we have more linear force.

Apart from that, as soon as you start moving, there is more friction from the air (i.e., drag) that you might want to consider.